# Which is the correct format for Lambda AWS PreSignUp Response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a VUE+Amplify project, it's almost done, but cognito does not offer mail duplication check, so i've to do it manually, as we know AWS has some triggers i'm using PreSignUp invoking a Lambda function, my code is:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();


exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
  var params = {
    UserPoolId: "us-east-1_xxxXXXxXX",
    AttributesToGet: ["email"]
  };

  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      callback(err)        // here is the error return
    } else {
      data.Users.forEach(function(usuario) {
        if(usuario.Attributes[0].Value == event.request.userAttributes.email){
          return {};
        }
      });
      callback(event);
    }
  });
}
```

but I dont understand what I am doing wrong, the lambda execution returns...

```
Object { code: "UserLambdaValidationException", name: "UserLambdaValidationException", message: "PreSignUp failed with error [object Object]." }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the event object

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i been doing, I Just added

 `callback (full, event);`

and not it works, but is there any way to cancel the Sign-up event and send a Custom message? If I send an empty object

 `callback (full, {} );`

Cognito returns
 { code: "InvalidLambdaResponseException", name: "InvalidLambdaResponseException", message: "Invalid version. Version should be 1" }
App.vue:204

Comment: Can't you just return event;?